# How to get posts which must match both custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have searched in the stackexchange site for an answer for this question. However, I did not find any posts can help me solve the following problem:

I have 2 custom taxonomies named **tax1** and **tax2**

I want to create a args for WP_Query which must meet the following conditions:
- The posts must be in both **tax2** and **tax2**
- The posts are in the custom post_type **posttype1**

I have tried to create the following args to get the posts but it did not work as I expected:

```
$query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'posttype1',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'offset' => 0,
        'orderby' => date,
        'order' => ASC,
        'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tax1',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array ( ... ), // an array of term
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tax2',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array ( ... ), // an array of term
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    );
```

Could anyone help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate: "but it did not work as I expected".

Comment: I mean this returned nothing

Comment: Please turn on all WordPress and PHP Debug levels. Then install [the Debug Bar and it's extensions](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/). You'll be able to show the complete query that doesn't work. Maybe there's a _fix_.

Comment: OK. The answer for why the above code did not work was my false. I defined wrong taxonomy slug :(. Thanks for your help kaiser.

Comment: Hmm. The above code worked OK when I selected two specific taxonomy term ids. However, when I selected "All Tax1" or/and "All Tax2" (I mean the term id is 0), the above code did not work. Do you have any idea?